# Publisher service writing logs with wrong time and publishing queue not showing transactions

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am getting following error in Publishing queue but publishing working fine.

> (80040E31) Query timeout expired Unable to get list of publishing queue items.SQLUtilities.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure SystemDAL.GetListData SystemBLST.lObjListPublishTransactions SystemBLST.IBLSystemST_GetListData ManagementInfo.GetListPublishQueue

I am running publisher service in debug mode and writing all output to a text file, interestingly log file writing wrong time. Time on server is correct, timezone in Tridion CMS is correct. I have restarted the server as well but still having wrong time in publisher log. I believe this wrong time is the issue why publishing queue is not showing transactions.

It was working well before but having this issue since yesterday.

Comment: Can you edit your question and its title; is it regarding the timestamp or the error?  Are you assuming one is correlated to the other?

Comment: I believe time is not correct in CMS and publishing queue trying to load transactions with wrong time and get stuck somewhere and gets timeout error.

Comment: Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 4):

This error is caused by your publish queue timing out.

Here's some of the steps i'd take to resolve this:

- Purge the list of items in the queue, either using filtering in the GUI and deleting smaller groups, or using the purge tool to wipe it.
- Increase the time outs in the SDL Tridion Configuration Manager snap-in
- Ensure you have the latest software rollup for SDL Tridion 2011

Comment: Why is the timestamp in the log showing the wrong time?

Comment: time on tridion server is 02:09 PM and I published a page and got following line in publisher log file.04:09:32.0448 <11668> Receiving deployment feedback for publish transaction [tcm:0-13406-66560] with status: Success.   Other logging file like cd_core has correct time.

Comment: I did run purge tool and it got finished without any error, If I open the "PUBLISH_TRANSACTIONS" table from the database i have only 1083 rows.